# Flutter - Check language on start

Tags: flutter

I´m trying to check language of device to show / hide some elements. I try similar to

```
 @override
      initState() {
        super.initState();    
     if (Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode == 'en') {
              en = true;
            } else {
              en = false;
            }
    }
```

But returns

```
 The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
I/flutter ( 8804): inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_LocalizationsScope) or inheritFromElement() was called before
I/flutter ( 8804): _FormViewPage.initState() completed.
I/flutter ( 8804): When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent
I/flutter ( 8804): widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor
I/flutter ( 8804): or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the
I/flutter ( 8804): inherited widget.
I/flutter ( 8804): Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively,
I/flutter ( 8804): initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which
I/flutter ( 8804): is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.
```

If i use `didChangeDependencies` doesn't return error but doesn't run the if..else sentence and i need to run on start.

So: Anybody know how can i check language properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it with  `WidgetsBinding` once the widget tree is ready.

```
 super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (Localizations.localeOf(context).countryCode == 'en') {
        en = true;
      } else {
        en = false;
      }
    });
```

For more info - [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)